# Including GZip, Expire headers, and etag; what else can be done to optimize .htaccess to improve a site's performance?

Tags: .htaccess

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript


#Expire Header
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 hours"
</FilesMatch>

FileETag none
```

This is what I found but I don't know if this is the best solution to speed up my web site

Comment: What is "best" always depends on what you *need*. There's no *absolute* "best".

Comment: https://muffinresearch.co.uk/avoiding-the-use-of-htaccess-for-performance/

Comment: you say that I do not need to modify the. htacces but how can I speed up my website then?

Comment: First figure out what exactly makes your website slow!

Comment: I just used Yslow and i want to get my website as close as possible to a good Overall performance score. So everything were i get a F. that is what i want to improve. ( expire headers, gzip, etag).

Comment: Whatever your .htaccess contains, the .htaccess itself will slow things down.  See http://www.eschrade.com/page/why-you-should-not-use-htaccess-allowoverride-all-in-production/ for an example of why.

Comment: @dcc instead of dropping a link, you might want to provide context.  Now my comment looks stupid, because I don't click seemingly random links. :)